# aws iam login to eb cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

im  trying to get eb cli working.

in my cmd i do

```
>eb init
```

which opens up a new terminal, which then soon asks for aws-access-id and aws-secret-key

```
You have not yet set up your credentials or your credentials are incorrect
You must provide your credentials.
(aws-access-id): xxxx
(aws-secret-key): xxxxxxxxxx
ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

im not 100% sure whether aws-access-id referes to my username, the email address that created it or user id....

same goes for the aws-secret-key , im assuming right now that its the password for the account not some 1 off secret key.

I have used the console login link to register the iam account and change the password.

I have set the permissions of this user group to be AdministratorAccess

##################################

what is aws-access-id:

my username?

the email address?

user id?

is there anything that looks wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Access keys`.

> Access keys are long-term credentials for an IAM user or the AWS account root user. You can use access keys to sign programmatic requests to the AWS CLI or AWS API (directly or using the AWS SDK).

If you have access to [IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/) and have sufficient privileges you can generate such keys for yourself. If not you need to contact your AWS administrator.
Please take a look at [Managing access keys for IAM users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html) for more information.

Comment: Is this still the case? When creating an Access Key I get a warning to use a better alternative such as "Use the AWS CLI V2 and enable authentication through a user in IAM Identity Center". Is there no way to reconcile aws cli's sso login with eb cli?